# MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or latter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

I am followin MVC Music Store tutorial but when i had to do scaffolding i got a problem with that. 
I got message "**MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or latter**".
What I have to do to fix this? Instal Visual 2012 or change sth on web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ASP.NET MVC 4, unfortunately MVC4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or higher. but I you can use scaffolding in MVC5.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is uninstall `EntitityFramework 6` from the project and add `EntitityFramework 5` from NuGet Packages. Then go ahead with the scaffolding as 
`EntitityFramework 5` in MVC supports scaffolding. After you have done it, you can update back your `EntitityFramework` to version 6, then everything should be working fine.